# maximum determinant of a (reduced) Laplacian matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics

Given a simple graph G with n vertices, its Laplacian matrix L is the difference of the degree matrix D and the adjacency matrix A of the graph. The matrix is singular and it's determinant is zero, but if we delete a row and column we obtain a new matrix M which has a positive determinant.

What is the largest possible determinant for any (n-1)×(n-1) matrix M?

Hadamard's Maximum Determinant Problem gives some bounds but these do not seem to be applicable.

Comment: The determinant is the number of spanning trees of $G$. The maximum number of spanning trees of a simple $n$-vertex graph is $n^{n-2}$, achieved by the complete graph $K_n$.

Comment: Thanks Richard, that answers the question I asked. What I didnt mention (silly me) was that I am only concerned with planar graphs. Complete graphs from $K_5$ are non-planar so planar graph determinants would not get near the complete graph bound for n>4, but at least I have an upper bound now.

Comment: For planar graphs, see http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0712.